# does not allow data from static types

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asmx

i m making an API in .net , that will communicate with its client with xml data.
client software can be in any language php,asp.net etc.
what is the best way to develop such API, 
i was trying to use the .net webservices', but [webmethods] does not allow non static data,
and in my API there are lots of things that will work only with the non static data.
can you please suggest any solution to this problem, ?
any way to develpop it without using .net webservies?

Comment: what do you mean by "non-static data"?

Comment: I think an example of what you mean would help here. Web-services work fine with most data. I'm *assuming* that by "static data" here you mean things like keywords, type-codes, etc that don't change frequently - but web-services won't distinguish this (it can't even tell). Web services certainly don't work with static classes, if that is what you mean - there is no object to send.

Comment: But you say "does not allow non-static" which is entirely the wrong way around...

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, you actually mean "does not allow static classes". So... Don't SE static class. I would suggest moving those static properties into a default instance:

```
class Foo {
    private static readonly Foo @default =
        new Foo();
    public static Foo Default { get { return @default; } }
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

}
```

And treat the `Foo.Default` object's properties like the existing static ones.

Note that with XmlSerializer you need a public ctor, hence I haven't called this a singleton, as *strictly speaking* it won't be.